# Mifare read APDU command recived 63 00

Tags: nfc, mifare

All!

I'm trying to read data from mifare card 1k.
to get ID
I send: 0xFF 0xCA 0x00 0x00 0x00
Recive: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 - ??? it's normal?

to load auth key to reader 
I send: 0xFF 0x82 0x00 0x00 0x06 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF
Recive: 90 00 - it's ok

to authenticate in block 01
I send: 0xFF 0x86 0x00 0x00 0x05 0x01 0x00 0x01 0x60 0x00
Recive: 90 00 - it's ok

to read data from block 01
I send: 0xFF 0xB0 0x00 0x01 0x0F
Recive: 63 00 - how a understand it's authentication error

I can't understand - why?

My code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Winscard.h"

LPTSTR          pmszReaders = NULL;
LPTSTR      pmszCards = NULL;
LPTSTR          pReader;
LPTSTR          pCard;
LONG            lReturn, lReturn2;
DWORD           cch = SCARD_AUTOALLOCATE;
SCARDCONTEXT    hSC;
SCARD_READERSTATE readerState;
LPCTSTR         readerName = L"ACS ACR1222 1S Dual Reader 0";
SCARDHANDLE     hCardHandle;
DWORD           dwAP;
BYTE            pbRecv[50];
DWORD           dwRecv;

BYTE            cmdGetData[] = {0xFF, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
BYTE            cmdLoadKey[] = {0xFF, 0x82, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF};
BYTE            cmdAuthBlock01[] = {0xFF, 0x86, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x60, 0x00};
BYTE            cmdReadBlock01[] = {0xFF, 0xB0, 0x00, 0x01, 0x0F};



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {

    lReturn = SCardEstablishContext(SCARD_SCOPE_USER, NULL, NULL, &hSC);
    if ( SCARD_S_SUCCESS != lReturn )
        printf("Failed SCardEstablishContext\n");
    else {
        lReturn = SCardListReaders(hSC, NULL, (LPTSTR)&pmszReaders, &cch );
        if (lReturn != SCARD_S_SUCCESS) {
            printf("Failed SCardListReaders\n");
        } else {
            pReader = pmszReaders;
            while ( '\0' != *pReader ) {
                printf("Reader: %S\n", pReader );
                pReader = pReader + wcslen((wchar_t *)pReader) + 1;
            }
        }

        memset(&readerState,0,sizeof(readerState));
        readerState.szReader = pmszReaders;

        lReturn = SCardConnect( hSC, pmszReaders, SCARD_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE, SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0 | SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1, &hCardHandle, &dwAP );
        if ( SCARD_S_SUCCESS != lReturn ) {
            printf("Failed SCardConnect\n");
            system("pause");
            exit(1);
        } else {
            printf("Success SCardConnect\n");
            switch ( dwAP ) {
                case SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0:
                    printf("Active protocol T0\n"); 
                    break;
                case SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1:
                    printf("Active protocol T1\n"); 
                    break;
                case SCARD_PROTOCOL_UNDEFINED:
                default:
                    printf("Active protocol unnegotiated or unknown\n"); 
                    break;
            }
        }

        lReturn = SCardTransmit(hCardHandle, SCARD_PCI_T1, cmdGetData, sizeof(cmdGetData), NULL, pbRecv, &dwRecv);
        if ( SCARD_S_SUCCESS != lReturn ) {
            printf("Failed SCardTransmit\n");
        } else {
            printf("Success SCardTransmit\n");
            printf("Read %u bytes\n", dwRecv);
            for(byte i=0;i<dwRecv;i++) {
                printf("%x ", pbRecv[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }


        lReturn = SCardTransmit(hCardHandle, SCARD_PCI_T1, cmdLoadKey, sizeof(cmdLoadKey), NULL, pbRecv, &dwRecv);
        if ( SCARD_S_SUCCESS != lReturn ) {
            printf("Failed SCardTransmit\n");
        } else {
            printf("Success SCardTransmit\n");
            printf("Read %u bytes\n", dwRecv);
            for(byte i=0;i<dwRecv;i++) {
                printf("%x ", pbRecv[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }


        lReturn = SCardTransmit(hCardHandle, SCARD_PCI_T1, cmdAuthBlock01, sizeof(cmdAuthBlock01), NULL, pbRecv, &dwRecv);
        if ( SCARD_S_SUCCESS != lReturn ) {
            printf("Failed SCardTransmit\n");
        } else {
            printf("Success SCardTransmit\n");
            printf("Read %u bytes\n", dwRecv);
            for(byte i=0;i<dwRecv;i++) {
                printf("%x ", pbRecv[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }


        lReturn = SCardTransmit(hCardHandle, SCARD_PCI_T1, cmdReadBlock01, sizeof(cmdReadBlock01), NULL, pbRecv, &dwRecv);
        if ( SCARD_S_SUCCESS != lReturn ) {
            printf("Failed SCardTransmit\n");
        } else {
            printf("Success SCardTransmit\n");
            printf("Read %u bytes\n", dwRecv);
            for(byte i=0;i<dwRecv;i++) {
                printf("%x ", pbRecv[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }


    }

    lReturn = SCardDisconnect(hCardHandle, SCARD_LEAVE_CARD);
    if ( SCARD_S_SUCCESS != lReturn ) {
        printf("Failed SCardDisconnect\n");
    } else {
        printf("Success SCardDisconnect\n");
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain why i got 63 00?
Thanks.

Comment: Try authenticating with command `88` instead of `86`, and then read the block. One possible authentication APDU can be: `{FF, 88, 00, 01, 60, 00}`).

Answer (score 2):

Afair your `read` command has to be: "`0xFF, 0xB0, 0x00, BLOCK, 0x10`". You send buffer length `0F` - which is decimal 15 - but you have to read 16 Byte, which is `0x10`.
Hope this helps